# Solution to the problem: $10^{x} - 10^{x+1} = -900$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having trouble isolating the variable in this scenario, is there a way to isolate and solve using exponential and logarithmic properties?

Comment: A problem involving the logarithm of a negative number?  Are you supposed to know about complex numbers for this?

Answer (score 1):

$10^x - 10^{x+1} = 10^x(1-10) = (10^x)(-9) = -900\\
10^x = 100 = 10^2\\
x = 2$

Comment: Is it possible to solve with logs and exponent properties?

Comment: we used some exponent properties in the problem above.  You could say $10^x = 100$ and apply the $log$ to both sides.  $x = \log_{10} 100 = 2$

Answer (score 0):

Write $10^x-10^{x+1}=10^x(1-10)=-9\cdot10^x$. Unfortunately this is a negative number for any real $x$, so there is no real solution.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I have edited the question to change the -900 to 900 it should be solvable now. This is a homemade problem I am just trying to understand the concept

Comment: The minus-sign problem was not with the $-900$, it's the $-9$ *inside the logarithm* on the left hand side.

Comment: The problem is that $10^{x+1}=10\cdot10^x$ is always greater than $10^x$, so the subtraction gives a negative number. The domain of the logarithm is made up of positive numbers only.

Comment: To refactor my question completely: (10^x) - 10^(x+1) = -900 this should work and the solution should be 2 but I have no idea how to solve it, I will update the title now as well

Comment: @spacecadetMJ, Andrei's answer should now help you solve the problem as it now stands:  $-900=10^x-10^{x+1}=10^x(1-10)=-9\cdot10^x$ implies $100=10^x$ after you divide by $-9$....